# Remove static block using xml from header.phtml

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, blocks, magento-1, static-block

In my `header.phtml` I've got the following code

```
<?php 
    echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('nwdrevslider/revslider')->setAlias('slidername')->setBlockId('sliderid')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

So I want to **remove it from the product view page** so to do so in my `catalog.xml` I've write the following code

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">

    <reference name="header">

       <remove name="slidername" />

        <!-- even tried following but didn't work -->

        <remove name="sliderid" />

        <!-- even tried following but didn't work -->

        <action method="unsetChild"><name>slidername</name></action>

        <!-- even tried following but didn't work -->

        <action method="unsetChild"><name>sliderid</name></action>

    </reference>

</catalog_product_view>
```

Using **Magento 1.7.0.2**.

Let me know if you want more information.

Revolution slide is been used

Comment: Only catalog page ? Share Your url

Comment: @Kothari : It's in my local can't share, Yes only from product view page I want it to be removed.

Comment: You using create block in phtml so not remove it from xml layout.

for this need use current product registry code

    Mage::registry('current_product');

    $product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); // check product id 

$product_id not exist then show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are calling the block directly so **xml** will not work. call it like this

```
if(!Mage::registry('current_product')) {

    echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('nwdrevslider/revslider')->setAlias('slidername')->setBlockId('sliderid')->toHtml(); 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the best practice.

First, **instead of generating the block directly in your `header.phtml` you should use your `local.xml` to assign the block to your template**:

```
<default>
    <reference name="header>
            <block type="cms/block" name="slidername">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>sliderid</block_id></action>
            </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Then in your `header.phtml` you can replace:

```
echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('nwdrevslider/revslider')->setAlias('slidername')->setBlockId('sliderid')->toHtml();
```

With:

```
echo  $this->getChildHtml('slidername');
```

Once you're done with this you can **add the following to your `local.xml`** :

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <remove name="slidername" />
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: Yes even I prefer this way but It's hard coded by some other developers in base file and I can't change it for a while...Thanks @RaphaelatDigitalPianism